clearing the signal_pending condition
The driver needs to finish some tasks using its wait queue after it receives the signal. My tests show that after the signal is received (for example SIGINT) the scheduler returns back immediately, and system becomes kind of hung if it happens in the loop.
Is there any mechanism like clear_signal_pending to allow wait queue function normally until driver is done and returns with respective error code?
Edit: I am not trying to receive signal. I am trying to prevent schedule() waking up process immediately because of signal pending.
If what I asked sounds line XY problem, let me ask differently:
add_wait_queue(&idev->wait, &wait);
do
{
    set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    schedule();
    // do something and break on specific condition
}
while(true);

The code above functions properly when there's no signal pending, returning to "do something" when wake_up_interruptible is issued by some other part (interrupt handler, timer callback, etc).
However when user presses the ^C at the user-space level, SIGINT goes down to the driver level, signal_pending() becomes true, and schedule() is being waken immediately every time it is called, causing CPU being busy with (almost) dead loop stopping servicing other operating system requests until cycle is broken.
How do I tell operating system at the driver level to discard received signal for now and perform schedule() properly until driver decides to act upon the signal (e.g. return with -EINTR to the user-space caller)?
Update: thanks to Ian Abbott for suggestion, but I decided to go different route. I create dedicated threads which control the hardware, and terminate when module is being unloaded. Therefore if user-space kernel call is being signaled, its wait can terminate immediately while threads continue supporting hardware till the transaction's logical end.

Does this answer your question? Signal handling in kernel-space IOW you're asking an XY question because a driver should not be trying to receive a signal.

clarified the question

Can't you just use TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE? If you need to "see" that a signal is pending first, start off at TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE and then switch to TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE after you have seen the pending signal.
